# Ubuntu 22.04, why do some PDFs not generate a preview when downloaded?

Tags: usb, printing, pdf

[image: pdf thumnails]

I can put the ones that have previews on to a USB stick, go to a public printer that takes USB sticks, and print out the PDFs no problem but the red icon ones with no preview, they don't even show up on the public printer as being on the USB stick.

How can I get a preview for every single PDF I download?

Comment: Can you check whether those files are corrupted? Do they open properly in your computer?

Comment: Do those PDFs require a password to print them out? The preview is generated by the print driver so, if a password is needed, some printer drivers cannot generate anything 